# irb on windows: "NameError: uninitialized constant PATH"

Tags: ruby, irb

Disclaimer: i'm a Ruby newbie

Problem: I'm following the instructions from  Web Application Testing in Ruby  (https://leanpub.com/watirbook/read#leanpub-auto-installation) but when I type PATH in irb, I get "NameError: uninitialized constant PATH."

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They were not talking about IRB but your shell instead, try ``echo $PATH``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't type `PATH` into irb, you type it into the console.